# CSS text hover underline animation inside of div

Tags: html, css, underline

I'm trying to animate an underline for a word on my webpage. It works, but the underline shows under the div that the text is inside. You can see on the snippet that the div is supposed to fill the whole display, but now you have to scroll down to see the underline. How can I make it show right under the text?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 150%;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: font-size 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: font-size 0.5s;
  -o-transition: font-size 0.5s;
  transition: font-size 0.5s;
}
div:hover {
  font-size: 200%;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); float: left;">
  <a>Webpage</a>
</div>
<div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(64, 64, 64); float: right;">
  <a>Photos</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line height of the anchors is modified in the parent.

Restore it to the default

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100vh;  /* this value is inherited by the a */
  font-size: 150%;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: font-size 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: font-size 0.5s;
  -o-transition: font-size 0.5s;
  transition: font-size 0.5s;
}
div:hover {
  font-size: 200%;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  line-height: initial;  /* added */
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); float: left;">
  <a>Webpage</a>
</div>
<div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(64, 64, 64); float: right;">
  <a>Photos</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Would like to know the reason for this.

Comment: @xxCodexx  The div has a line-height of 100vh. The a is inside the div, so this setting **cascades** to it, and since it is a huge value, it sets the faked underline very low. Just setting it again to *initial* will restore the original value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an a bracket, I would put a div inside it.

```
<div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(64, 64, 64); float: right;"><div id="hoverDiv">Photos</div></div>
```

and then in the CSS, you just show the bottom border of the div in blue on the hover.

Sorry I don't have time to do all the code, but it's a first draft... hope it can give you a good idea !

Comment: Don't want to argue with you, but I'm curious to know why it would not ?

Comment: You can try it for yourself with the snippet. The underline still shows under the main div.

Comment: Yeah, ok, I meant like you'll have to redo your code to use a div and only show the bottom border. I was giving you another idea of how to do the same thing. I saw that someone gave you a solution more in touch with your current solution, so it's all good :D

Answer (score 1):

you may use flex and background-size:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
div {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
a {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, currentcolor, currentcolor) bottom center no-repeat;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-size: 0 3px;
}
a:hover {
  background-size: 100% 3px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); "><a>Webpage</a>
</div>
<div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(64, 64, 64); "><a>Photos</a>
</div>
```

you may also use display:table

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
html {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
body {
  display: table-row;
}
div {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, currentcolor, currentcolor) bottom center no-repeat;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-size: 0 3px;
}
a:hover {
  background-size: 100% 3px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); "><a>Webpage</a>
</div>
<div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(64, 64, 64); "><a>Photos</a>
</div>
```

both example can use the pseudo `:after` if you turn `<a>` to `inline-block` element